# Entity Framework 6 Force to always get database information

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to change a c# winforms application from single user to multiuser. I'm using Generic Repositories, AutoMapper and unitOfWork. The context is injected via constructor in repository and when I create the object sets i use the mergeOption: OverwriteChanges, this works for some tables but not for all of them, so I'm interested in somehow make the setting of mergeOption: OverwriteChanges globally.

```
public Repository(ObjectContext context)
        {
               _exHandler = new ExceptionHandler(new Logger());
                _internalList = new List<T1>();
                _objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
                _objectSet.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
                _context = context;
        }

public Controller(IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory)
        {
           
            _unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;

            _unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkFactory.Create();

            LoadRepositories();

            **var objSetProps = _unitOfWork.Context.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObjectSet<>));**
            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo objSetProp in objSetProps)
            {
                ObjectQuery objSet = (ObjectQuery)objSetProp.GetValue(_unitOfWork.Context, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, null, null);
                objSet.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
            }

        }
```

I've tried to use reflection but var objSetProps = _unitOfWork.Context.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObjectSet<>)); doen't return any property.

Other details :
I've tried somehow to use the approach to recreate the context (hold in uow) and dispose it asap by introducing IUnitOfWorkFactory.Before using IUnitOfWorkFactory the code implementation look like :

```
 public interface IDbEntity
        {
            int Id { get; set; }
            bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        }
     
     public interface IRepository<T, T1>
            where T : class, IDbEntity
            where T1 : class, IDbEntity
        {
            int Add(T1 newEntityViewModel);
            void AddRange(List<T1> newEntities);
            void Remove(int id);
            void RemoveFromDb(int id);
            List<T1> Find(Expression<Func<T1, bool>> predicate);
            T1 FindById(int id);
            List<T1> FindAll();
            T FindByIdInContext(int id);
            int GetNextId();
            List<T> FindAllInContext();
        }
        
        internal class DbRepository<T, T1> : IRepository<T, T1>
            where T : class, IDbEntity
            where T1 : class, IDbEntity
        {
            protected ObjectSet<T> _objectSet;
            protected List<T1> _internalList;
            protected ObjectContext _context;
    
            public DbRepository(ObjectContext context)
            {
                try
                {
                    
                    _internalList = new List<T1>();
                    _objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
                    _context = context;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error(ex.Message);
                    throw;
                }
            }
    
    
    
            public int Add(T1 newEntityViewModel)
            {
                try
                {
                    var entityDto = AutoMapperConfiguration.GetMapperConfiguration().Map<T1, T>(newEntityViewModel);
                    _objectSet.AddObject(entityDto);
    
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    
                    //check id 
                    return entityDto.Id;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error(ex.Message);
                    throw;
                }
            }
    
    
            public List<T1> Find(Expression<Func<T1, bool>> predicate)
            {
                try
                {
                    var listT1 = AutoMapperConfiguration.GetMapperConfiguration().Map<List<T1>>(_objectSet.Where(q => !q.IsDeleted));
                    var result = listT1.Where(predicate.Compile()).ToList();
    
                    return result;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   log.Error(ex.Message);
                    throw;
                }
            }
    
            public List<T1> FindAll()
            {
                try
                {
                    var listT1 = AutoMapperConfiguration.GetMapperConfiguration().Map<List<T1>>(_objectSet.Where(q => !q.IsDeleted));
                    return listT1;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error(ex.Message);
                    throw;
                }
            }
    
        }
        
        
        public interface IUnitOfWork
        {
            IRepository<User, User_ViewModel> Users { get; }
            IRepository<Type, Type_ViewModel> Types { get; }
            
            /// and a lot more repositories
    
            ObjectContext Context { get; }
            void Commit();
        }
        
        
        internal class DbUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
        {
            private DbRepository<User, User_ViewModel> _users = null;
            private DbRepository<Type, Type_ViewModel> _types = null;
           
           
           
            private readonly ObjectContext _context;
            private readonly EntityConnection _connectionString;
    
       
            public ObjectContext Context { get { return _context; } }
    
            public DbUnitOfWork(EntityConnection connectionString)
            {
                try
                {
                    _connectionString = connectionString;
                    _context = new ObjectContext(connectionString, true);
                    _context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error(ex.Message);
                    throw;
                }
            }
    
            public IRepository<User, User_ViewModel> Users
            {
                get
                {
                    return _users ?? (_users = new DbRepository<User, User_ViewModel>(_context));
                }
            }
    
    
            public IRepository<Type, Type_ViewModel> Types
            {
                get
                {
                    return _types ?? (_types = new DbRepository<Type, Type_ViewModel>(_context));
                }
            }
    
    
    
            public void Commit()
            {
                try
                {
                   _context.SaveChanges();
    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error(ex.Message);
                    throw;
                }
            }
    
        }
        
        DbController.cs
        public partial class DbController
        {
            protected readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
            
            protected readonly IRepository<User, User_ViewModel> _userRepository;
            protected readonly IRepository<Type, Type_ViewModel> _typeRepository;
            
            
            public SafeIOController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
            {
               
    
                _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
                
                _userRepository = _unitOfWork.Users;
                _typeRepository = _unitOfWork.Types;
                
            }
    
            public void Save()
            {
                _unitOfWork.Commit();
            }
        }
        Controller_User.cs
        public partial class DbController
        {
           
    
            public List<User_ViewModel> GetAllUsers()
            {
                try
                {
                    
                    return _userRepository.FindAll();
    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _exHandler.LogErrorMessage(Constants_Exception.DB_EXCEPTION_MSG, ex, _exHandler.GetCurrentMethod());
                    throw;
                }
            }
    
    
            
        }
    
    

and then in winforms app 
        
          

  _unitOfWork = new DbUnitOfWork(connectionString);
  _controller = new DbController(_unitOfWork);
```

How can I properly implement unitOfWork in order to have the latest information from db inside my context?

Comment: It's very questionable if you really want this. Any query from the database will run the risk of overwriting local changes. Keep in mind that queries may contain more entities than just the root entity and maybe lazy loading is involved. I sense that the underlying problem is in the context life cycle management. You contexts live too long and you want to refresh their contents. Side note: try to move away from the deprecated ObjectContext, start using DbContext (that doesn't even have this option, it was deemed unnecessary).

Comment: Indeed lazy loading is envolved. I'm also using SqlTableDependency to get notifications in sort of real time manner when database is changed externally by other user. So when I get the notification, I will now that updates have been performed and I should somehow to refresh the context, refresh the entities involved in the change. I cannot drop the context and recreate another one because the active user who is receiving the notification may be working in other tab and he can perform updates on other entities.

Comment: The mere fact that you're talking about "*the* context" tells enough. A windows application shouldn't have one context. It will blow up with application life time and things will get increasingly slower. Context life cycle management in windows applications is something that should be designed and implemented carefully.

Answer (score 0):

DbContexts are designed to operate in a short-lived manner. This is relatively easy to manage in a Web application since the workflow is essentially Request and Response so a DbContext fits quite well to be scoped to live for the duration of a request. It can be a bit more challenging to avoid the temptation of keeping a DbContext alive throughout a Windows application lifespan, or even a form instance's lifespan. The reality is that to save performance and your sanity with multi-user or background changes, you should do everything in your power to keep DbContexts alive only as long as absolutely necessary.

For example, it may be tempting to associate an instance of a DbContext to a Form so that when the form is initialized / loaded, the data for that form is loaded into the DbContext and all event handlers etc. interact with tracked entity instances. Elements like NotifyPropertyChanged are tempting as edits to an entity on one form / region can auto-magically refresh bindings on another, all the while the DbContext can call SaveChanges to persist. It works perfectly fine in smaller, single user systems with relatively small amounts of data and/or short operating times. It will easily fall into a steaming heap of complexity and performance pitfalls when applied to larger, multi-user systems that are expected to be running all day.

This design is not ideal for a number of reasons. Firstly, performance given the longer a DbContext is alive and the more entities it tracks, the slower any/all operations to read & update become. Memory usage balloons considerably through the life of the application. The more entities a DbContext is tracking, the more references it has to sift through to resolve and relate as you make changes or load entities with relatable references. You also run into stale data issues as tracked instances do not automatically refresh from data state so they won't see changes made by other DbContext instances or external systems. DbContexts will gladly overwrite current data with stale data, or if you're lucky, throw concurrency errors if you are configured to use row versioning. (involving more logic to try and handle these gracefully) Lastly you run into all kinds of problems when issues happen and changes need to be discarded or processes that share *the* DbContext want to selectively save changes to the database. `DbContext.SaveChanges()` will attempt to write everything that is modified and tracked at that point in time, whether you intend for it to or not. (I.e. code to save an audit record or log entry for an issue encountered validating or saving data may end up failing because the DbContext cannot save the affected entities when you want to save the log entry. It becomes a juggling act of detaching and attaching entities or dumping and recreating a DbContext reference that is shared everywhere.

If you have a method to refresh data on a form, that method should "scope" a boundary for a DbContext instance. This method can be called when a form loads, as well as triggered by other events such as a refresh timer or a signal from other users that relevant data has changed. Each call to refresh data is a new DbContext instance so there is no stale data to be concerned about. For triggered refreshes, the views are bound to ViewModels rather than entities (Think MVVM or MVP) so that when data state is refreshed, if there is existing view model state to consider, the code can determine whether to overwrite or possibly notify the user of conflicting changes.  Committing changes to data involves loading the data state again, then transposing the relevant details from the view model into the entity before saving the change. Again, the DbContext scope is only so long as the operation so there is effectively no window for stale data. You do want to consider tracking and checking something like a RowVersion/Timestamp between the ViewModel (from when it was populated from the data model) and data model at that point in time to detect possible changes since.

That said, revising a system built around single-user access into something that works efficiently for multiple users can involve a considerable amount of work depending on the assumptions made and how the DbContext's lifetime had been scoped. Since you are working with a Unit Of Work pattern I might suggest having a look at the implementation of the DbContextScope from Mehdime on how you might inject a Scope Factory (UoW) into Presenters/Controllers/Services while repositories get a Scope Locator. (https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope) You might not be at a point where you can swap out to use that library, but it may be possible to adapt your UoW implementation to leverage a similar way so that you can create a UoW scope within operations/events which manages the lifespan of the DbContext where the Repositories use the Locator to find the appropriate scope to get a DbContext reference from.

Comment: I've to admit that I tried to somehow shorten the lifecycle of the ObjectContext by introducing IUnitOfWorkFactory. So an instance of IUnitOfWorkFactory is passed via constructor to Controller which will create an instance of uow and load all the repositories. But then the application was very very slow maybe perhaps in the controller method I had imbricated (using var unitofwork = _unitofworkfactory.Create())